# Set-like Data Structure without `Ord`?

Tags: haskell, set

Given the following types:

```
import Data.Set as Set

-- http://json.org/

type Key = String

data Json = JObject Key (Set JValue)
            | JArray JArr
            deriving Show

data JObj = JObj Key JValue
            deriving Show

data JArr = Arr [JValue] deriving Show

data Null = Null deriving Show

data JValue = Num Double
              | S String
              | B Bool
              | J JObj
              | Array JArr
              | N Null
               deriving Show
```

I created a `JObject Key (Set Value)` with a single element:

```
ghci> JObject "foo" (Set.singleton (B True))
JObject "foo" (fromList [B True])
```

But, when I tried to create a 2-element Set, I got a compile-time error:

```
ghci> JObject "foo" (Set.insert (Num 5.5) $ Set.singleton (B True))

<interactive>:159:16:
    No instance for (Ord JValue) arising from a use of ‘insert’
    In the expression: insert (Num 5.5)
    In the second argument of ‘JObject’, namely
      ‘(insert (Num 5.5) $ singleton (B True))’
    In the expression:
      JObject "foo" (insert (Num 5.5) $ singleton (B True))
```

So I asked, "Why is it necessary for `JValue` to implement the `Ord` typeclass?"

The docs on [Data.Set](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/libraries/containers-0.5.5.1/Data-Set.html) answer that question.

> The implementation of Set is based on size balanced binary trees (or trees of bounded balance)

But, is there a Set-like, i.e. non-ordered, data structure that does not require `Ord`'s implementation that I can use?

Comment: You can use `deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)` to derive the needed instances, so the `Ord` requirement is not a big deal.

Comment: @chi, I'm thinking a trie would be more appropriate.

Comment: Another common approach to implementing sets is to use a hash map. Of course, this requires specifying a hashing function. For a generic implementation, see how the Hashable class is defined [(link)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashable-1.1.2.2/docs/Data-Hashable.html#t:Hashable) and how (pure) hash maps are implemented [(link)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.5.1/docs/Data-HashMap-Lazy.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will pretty much always need at least `Eq` to implement a set (or at least the *ability* to write an `Eq` instance, whether or not one exists). Having *only* `Eq` will give you a horrifyingly inefficient one. You can improve this with `Ord` or with `Hashable`.

One thing you might want to do here is use a trie, which will let you take advantage of the nested structure instead of constantly fighting it.

You can start by looking at [generic-trie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-trie-0.3.0.1/docs/Data-GenericTrie.html). This does not appear to offer anything for your `Array` pieces, so you may have to add some things.

#### Why `Eq` is not good enough

The simplest way to implement a set is using a list:

```
type Set a = [a]

member a [] = False
member (x:xs) | a == x = True
              | otherwise = member a xs

insert a xs | member a xs = xs
            | otherwise = a:xs
```

This is no good (unless there are very few elements), because you may have to traverse the entire list to see if something is a member.

To improve matters, we need to use some sort of tree:

```
data Set a = Node a (Set a) (Set a) | Tip
```

There are a lot of different kinds of trees we can make, but in order to use them, we must be able, at each node, to decide which of the branches to take. If we only have `Eq`, there is no way to choose the right one. If we have `Ord` (or `Hashable`), that gives us a way to choose.

The trie approach structures the tree based on the structure of the data. When your type is deeply nested (a list of arrays of records of lists...), either hashing or comparison can be very expensive, so the trie will probably be better.

#### Side note on `Ord`

Although I don't think you should use the `Ord` approach here, it very often is the right one. In some cases, your particular type may not *have* a natural ordering, but there is *some* efficient way to order its elements. In this case you can play a trick with `newtype`:

```
newtype WrappedThing = Wrap Thing

instance Ord WrappedThing where
  ....

newtype ThingSet = ThingSet (Set WrappedThing)
insertThing thing (ThingSet s) = ThingSet (insert (Wrap thing) s)
memberThing thing (ThingSet s) = member (WrapThing) s
...
```

Yet another approach, in some cases, is to define a "base type" that is an `Ord` instance, but only export a `newtype` wrapper around it; you can use the base type for all your internal functions, but the exported type is completely abstract (and not an `Ord` instance).

Comment: Could you say please explain, `Having only Eq will give you a horrifyingly inefficient one.`?

Comment: Basically, if you want to, say, check whether an element is in this set or not, your only option is to check all elements in the set. With `Ord` you'd be able to use binary search, which is MUCH faster.

Comment: Doesn't sometjing like *scrap your boilerplate* allow a generic structure based implementation on *any* data types? Or is the Arr too opaque and need explicit support added for the generic decomposition traversal?

Comment: @jdlugosz, I don't actually know. I know approximately nothing about GHC generics. As far as I can *tell*, the `generic-trie` package does not support that, but I *imagine* specialized `Array` support could be added without any theoretical difficulties.